# Searchbar not refreshing UIbutton color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uisearchbar

Here is my headache... Hope someone has the medecine.

The situation
- I have a searchbar linked to a tableview just below
- Tableview cell is made of 1 label and 1 button
- The button is a "favorite" button linked to coredata
- If the text of the label does exist in coredata, its color is brown
- If the text does not exist in coredata, its color is grey. If it is pressed, it turns to brown, and the text of the lable is registered in coredata

The headache
- Everything is works perfectly for the first filtering (everything is in place, buttons colors appear correctly wether the text is registered ir not, and registering by clicking on the button works perfectly fine BUT...
- when the search changes, cells are perfectly (un)filtered but not the button: those who should appear ingrey appear in brown
- If I change screen and come back everything is reset and buttons colors are OK

I can't find out how to refresh the button's title color during the search. Buttons' title is text. Any hint?

Code in CellForRowAt

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = searchTbv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchTbvCell

    if searhing {
        cell.searchLbl.text = mySearch[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        cell.searchLbl.text = dataSearch.searchItem[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

Code for the search bar

```
extension SearchVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    searhing = true

    mySearch = dataSearch.searchItem.filter({$0.lowercased().folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: .current).prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})

    searchTbv.reloadData()

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searhing = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchTbv.reloadData()

}
```

Code to set button color (code located in the custom cell class):

```
class SearchTbvCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK: OUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var searchLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    fetchFromCoreData()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    fetchFromCoreData()
}


@IBAction func favoriteBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Set fav button color to brown if selected/tapped
    searchBtn.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)

    // Permanently record selection as favorite into coredata
    recordPermanently()
}



//MARK: METHODS

// Fetch contents from CoreData and up-date button's color consequently
func fetchFromCoreData () {
    // Create a reference to container
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    // Create a context from the container
    let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
    // Prepare a request and sorting
    let myRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MyFavorites")
    myRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"favoriteWines = %@", searchLbl.text!)
    do {
        let results = (try managedContext?.fetch(myRequest))!
        for _ in results {
            searchBtn.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    catch{}
}


// Record permanently in core data and changethe button's color
func recordPermanently(){
    // Create a reference to container
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
    // Create a context from the container
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    // Create an entity to manage records
    let recordEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MyFavorites", in: managedContext)!
    // Create a new record
    let newRecord = NSManagedObject(entity: recordEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
    // Pass values to new record
    newRecord.setValue(searchLbl.text!, forKeyPath: "favoriteWines")
    // Save record
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        searchBtn.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print("Failed to save permanently. \(error), \(error.userInfo)" )
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where do you set the button color?

Comment: The button is set in the Interface builder. The color is set after checking if the label text exist in core data. if yes, then its title is set to browm. This part of the code is located in the custom cell class

Comment: My guess is your problem happens because the cells are reused. Try the answer I suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally fix this issue just by adding cell.searchBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal) to the cellForRowAt code (as below).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = searchTbv.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchTbvCell

    if searhing {
        cell.searchLbl.text = mySearch[indexPath.row]
        cell.searchBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal) // This line has fixed the problem

        if cell.searchLbl.text == myProperties.isInCoreData {
            cell.searchBtn.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)
        }
        else {
            cell.searchBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    else {
        cell.searchLbl.text = dataSearch.searchItem[indexPath.row]
        cell.searchBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .normal) // This line has fixed the problem
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: typed in browser, not tested in Xcode

You haven't indicated where and how you are setting the color of the button, but I recommend that you do this in `willDisplayCell`:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,  forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.label.text.existsInCoreCata() {
         cell.button.setTitleColor(.brown, for: .normal)
    }
    else {
        cell.button.setTitleColor(.grey, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

`existsInCoreCata()` is your code where you check if the label exists in CoreData.